# Searching for a book about a transporter company

Tags: story-identification

In the early 1960s, the Science Fiction Book Club offered a book with a plot about a transporter company which initially couldn't get the transporters to work.

Because they had so many false starts, when they finally opened in Manhattan they couldn't get any press to come to the opening.

They begin operations and become enormously popular.   As I remember it, you step into the equivalent of an elevator, the doors close, then open and you're at the new location.

But then someone doesn't show up at the other end and is lost in space.   And it may have been some kind of conspiracy that this "accident" happened.

Or something like that.

Anyone know the name of this novel?

Answer (score 5):

["All the Colors of Darkness"](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/969433.All_the_Colors_of_Darkness) (1963) by Lloyd Biggle, Jr, published by the SFBC in 1964.

> The Universal Transmitting Company's breakthough stands to make its directors fortunes. Step into a booth in Manhatten and instantaneously you arrive at your destination, anywhere in the world. While hinting at the consequences for the freight, railroad and airline industries, "All the Colors of Darkness" mostly concentrates on a detective plot around this technological marvel. On the first day of operation, several "passengers" go missing, but these persons have no public records, no relatives and no one, but the teleport operators, notice their passing. Our hero is detailed to find them.