# Short story about teleport trips and passengers going missing

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, teleportation

I know that there are a lot of this kind of question but I've looked through as many as I can find and none fit my recollection of this story.

- There's a world where humans are able to teleport long distances, by visiting a central hub, like an airport, to do so.
- There's some talk about how occasionally people just don't show up the other end, but statistically it's still safer than air travel etc.
- Over the course of the story, the main character "goes missing" and it turns out that the teleport streams are being hijacked to build a secret resistance to something.

My memory gets fuzzy there but I'd really like to re-read it.

As I recall, it was likely in an anthology that my parents had. They had a lot of old school anthologies. Ones that I remember were edited by James White and Isaac Asimov, I believe.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember when you read it?  Was it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: it was likely in an anthology that my parents had. they had a lot of old school anthologies. ones that I remember were edited by james white and isaac asimov i believe.

Comment: In the novel [All the colours of darkness](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69380/searching-for-a-book-about-a-transporter-company) people go missing in teleporters, but IIRC it's aliens involved in it.

Comment: @user1356743, it's always best to [edit] your question and put that info in. I've done that for you in this case (pending a review) so you don't have to, but it's good to know for future reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to be a week for asking about stories by Lloyd Biggle Jr.  You are describing the plot line of the novel *All The Colors of Darkness* (1963). From the cover blurb:

> In the summer of 1986, the Universal Transmitting Company, after a
> long series of inexplicable failures, public indifference, and
> financial problems, has finally perfected a matter transmitter capable
> of transporting a person instantaneously from terminals scattered
> throughout the United States to any major city in foreign countries.
> Chief Engineer Ted Arnold's genius had paid off - the transmitter
> represents man's ultimate conquest of time.
>
> Opening day in New York City is a tremendous success, with throngs of
> travelers crowding into the terminal. But on the second day of
> operations two women fail to arrive at their destinations and cannot
> be traced. UTC enlists the services of private detective Jan Darzek.
>
> Darzek discovers that the disappearances were engineered by two women
> in various disguises, that their identification papers were false, and
> that no friends reported them missing. Where Darzek arrives when he
> follows up these clues and what he discovers make a strange tale of
> extraterrestrial adventures and gripping suspense ....

There is a follow-up novel about Darzek's subsequent employment by these same extraterrestrials *Watchers of the Dark*. It seems "private detective" is not a common occupation in other parts of the universe.

Comment: If so it's a duplicate of [Searching for a book about a transporter company](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69380/searching-for-a-book-about-a-transporter-company) although the answer there was never accepted.

Comment: Given that "All the Colors..." is a novel, is there a short story version of it?

Comment: I think not.  I have the 1964 Doubleday hardcover, where there is no mention of earlier publication.

Comment: this is indeed it, I must have misremembered it as a short story. markes as the answer, thank you!